# Add to a Total in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, calculation

I'm trying to make a form work... I have the basic code and I'm working to modify the orderTotal (set to 0 initially) and add to it based on what the user clicks. I'm looking to use simple vanilla Javascript with no server.

```js
function processOrder() {
  orderTotal = 0;
  sizeOfPizza();
  crustOfPizza();

  //displayoutput(); 

  var total = sizeOfPizza();
  document.getElementById("orderTotal").value.display
}

//display choice of size of pizza
function sizeOfPizza() {
  var size = document.getElementsByName("size");
  if (size[0].checked) //if Personal is checked
  {
    orderTotal += 5.00 //add $5 to the total price
  } else if (size[1].checked) //if Medium is checked
  {
    orderTotal += 8.00 //add $8 to the total price 
  } else if (size[2].checked) //if Large is checked
  {
    orderTotal += 10.00 //add $10 to the total price 
  } else if (size[3].checked) //if Extra Large is checked
  {
    orderTotal += 12.00 //add $12 to the total price 
  } else if (size[4].checked) //if Holy Pizza is checked
  {
    orderTotal += 20.00 //add $20 to the total price 
  }
}
```

```html
<h3> Select Size </h3>

<form action="" id="pizza-size">
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="Personal"> Personal (4 Slices) <br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="Medium"> Medium (8 slices)<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="Large"> Large (10 slices) <br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="Extra Large"> Extra Large (12 slices)<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="Holy Pizza"> Holy Pizza Batman (24 slices) <br>
</form>
<br>

<input type="button" onclick="processOrder()" value="Preview Order">
<p>Total will appear here: </p>
<p id="orderTotal"> </p>
```

So basically if the user selects the medium pizza I want 8.00 added to the orderTotal and displayed...but I'm not sure how to make it display (and also to make sure it's calculating).

Thanks!

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("orderTotal").innerText = total;`, and don't forget to `return orderTotal` at the end of your `sizeOfPizza` function(since you're assign a value from it). Should solve your problem

Comment: That didn't work... it still doesn't display the calculation. 

function processOrder () {
 orderTotal=0;
 sizeOfPizza ();
 crustOfPizza();

 //displayoutput(); 
 
   document.getElementById("orderTotal").innerHTML = orderTotal
  
}

//display choice of size of pizza

function sizeOfPizza() {
  var size = document.getElementsByName("size");
  if (size[0].checked) //if Personal is checked
  {
 orderTotal += 5.00 //add $5 to the total price
  }
  return orderTotal
}

Comment: please check the answer I just posted, it's the full solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fix, mind the comments with `FIX` label

```js
function processOrder() {
  // FIX: you don't need this variable since it's not accessible from other functions
  // orderTotal = 0;

  sizeOfPizza();

  // FIX: this function does not exist, put it back when you define it
  // crustOfPizza();

  //displayoutput(); 
  
  var total = sizeOfPizza();

  // FIX: use this approach
  document.getElementById("orderTotal").innerText = total;
}

//display choice of size of pizza
function sizeOfPizza() {
  // FIX: put the variable here so rest of this function can access it
  let orderTotal = 0;
  
  var size = document.getElementsByName("size");
  if (size[0].checked) //if Personal is checked
  {
    orderTotal += 5.00 //add $5 to the total price
  }
  else if (size[1].checked) //if Medium is checked
  {
    orderTotal += 8.00 //add $8 to the total price 
  }
  else if (size[2].checked) //if Large is checked
  {
    orderTotal += 10.00 //add $10 to the total price 
  }
  else if (size[3].checked) //if Extra Large is checked
  {
    orderTotal += 12.00 //add $12 to the total price 
  }
  else if (size[4].checked) //if Holy Pizza is checked
  {
    orderTotal += 20.00 //add $20 to the total price 
  }
  // FIX: return the result
  return orderTotal;
}
```

```html
<h3>Select Size</h3>

<form action="" id="pizza-size">
 <input type="radio" name="size" value="Personal" /> Personal (4 Slices) <br />
 <input type="radio" name="size" value="Medium" /> Medium (8 slices)<br />
 <input type="radio" name="size" value="Large" /> Large (10 slices) <br />
 <input type="radio" name="size" value="Extra Large" /> Extra Large (12 slices)<br />
 <input type="radio" name="size" value="Holy Pizza" /> Holy Pizza Batman (24 slices) <br />
</form>
<br />

<input type="button" onclick="processOrder()" value="Preview Order" />
<p>Total will appear here:</p>
<p id="orderTotal"></p>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, I very much appreciate your detailed explanation of the fixes.

Comment: Glad it works for you, if you need to implement the `crustOfPizza` function, please consider to make the sum as `var total = sizeOfPizza() + crustOfPizza()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `document.getElementById("orderTotal").value.display` by `document.getElementById("orderTotal").innerHTML = orderTotal`.This, as you may guess, sets the contents of the `<p>` to orderTotal. Your previous line did not even reference orderTotal. Idk if it would have worked with `= orderTotal` at the end, but I know my version will work.

Comment: This doesn't display the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, youre setting `total` to `sizeOfPizza()` which doesnt return any value, therefore `total` is null. There is also a space between `sizeOfPizza` and the `()` which could affect the execution of that function. You should also change all these `if else` statements to an iteration through the array `size` or `switch case` statement. You don't set the value of the `orderTotal` element either. To do that just do `document.getElementById("orderTotal").textContent = orderTotal;`

Try this out and see if it works. If not, reference me the error messages